# Break when a register has an specific value?

Tags: windbg

Any way to make Windbg to break when a specific value is assigned to the `eax` register? I know one of the functions in my program is returning an specific error, it would be very fast to find the guilty this way.

Answer (score 4):

You can set a breakpoint on all your suspect functions and then check the `eax` register value like so:

```
bp myAddress ".if (@retreg == dodgyVal) {walk the stack and do other cool stuff} .else {gc}"
```

See [conditional breakpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556853%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and also [pseudo-register syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for available register values

Comment: Yeah, this may work. I was wondering if there was a shortcut to break  when a register changes of value. Usually the suspect function is a long list.