# How to break on register value

Tags: windbg

I'd like to break in my function when eax is equal to 1800.
I have tried to make single steps until eax is equal to 1800 but it steps once and quit the .while.

```
bp myProgram!myFunction ".while(eax!=0n1800){p}"
```

Any idea?

Comment: You probably need a breakpoint in a different place than the entry point of your application. Possible duplicate of [Break when a register has an specific value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973882/break-when-a-register-has-an-specific-value)

Comment: My breakpoint is at the entry point of a function. My problem is that I don't know where but when I should break. So I'd like to make Windbg debugging step by step inside my function until eax==1800.

Comment: Can you write some example code (C++?) so that I know what your function looks like? I guess it's more than just a simple loop. based on that example we could possibly find an approach which also works for your production code.