# How to set a conditional breakpoint on register's value in windbg?

Tags: windbg

I wonder if there is a way in windbg to set a breakpoint in all over the code when one of the register get a specific value or point to specific value.

to be more specific, somewhere in the code return "Err". I want to set a breakpoint that whenever EAX or other registers point to somthing like "Err", stop the code.

also I must say that there is no way to find "Err" in disassemblers.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, because there's no hardware support for it. Also, it would slow down your program a lot (my guess: factor of thousands) since you would execute a lot of code basically after every single assembler instruction. Someone may correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16981358/480982

Comment: @Thomas Weller, thanks. I saw the link, but it know the function. I don't have any suggestion on where to set the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

a break point is always tied to an address be it software breakpoint or hardware breakpoint

if you use a memory breakpoint it would be triggered on a page boundary (page_gaurd_violation)

other than that you have to single step

you can try windbgs wt (watch and trace command with a depth argument ) 
combined with a generic break-point address if You want to watch only eax (the return value of any call )

an example below

os **windows 7 sp1 32 bit**
windbg version **10.0.16299.15**
debuggee **calc.exe**
generic breakpoint **calc!WinMain**

command used **wt -l 8 -or**

before windbg breaks it would have traced around 7500 calls in this depth

```
>wc -l foo.txt & head foo.txt
7679 foo.txt

0:000> bp calc!WinMain
0:000> wt -l 8 -or
    3     0 [  0] ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak
   11     0 [  1]   ntdll!_SEH_epilog4 eax = 0
    4    11 [  0] ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak eax = 0
>> No match on ret
    4    11 [  0] ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak
   12     0 [  0] ntdll!LdrpInitializeProcess
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be 
    1     0 [  1]   ntdll!NtQueryInformationProcess
```

and you know eax has 88 and you want to check for it you can employ some grep magic like this

```
>grep -i "eax = .*88" foo.txt
   21     0 [  7]               msvcrt!_SEH_prolog4 eax = ef388
   21     0 [  8]                 KERNELBASE!_SEH_prolog4 eax = ee788
   14     0 [  8]                 ntdll!RtlpAllocateDebugInfo eax = 2c7b88
   21     0 [  7]               ntdll!_SEH_prolog4 eax = ef388
   44     0 [  8]                 ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap eax = 2c88c0
   57     0 [  8]                 ntdll!RtlDebugAllocateHeap eax = 2c88c0
    3     0 [  8]                 ntdll!RtlpAllocateHeap eax = 2c88c0
   15     0 [  8]                 ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap eax = 2c88c0
    6     0 [  7]               ole32!CPageAllocator::CPageAllocator eax = 76b88814
    6     0 [  7]               ole32!CPageAllocator::CPageAllocator eax = 76b87688
    6     0 [  7]               ole32!CPageAllocator::CPageAllocator eax = 76b86788
    3     0 [  6]             ole32!`dynamic initializer for 'arDcomInterfaces'' eax = 76a87988
   32     0 [  8]                 ole32!_onexit eax = 76a7e88b
   31    96 [  7]               ole32!ComVerifierSettings::ComVerifierSettings eax = 76b88aef
  104     0 [  8]                 ntdll!RtlDebugAllocateHeap eax = 2ca880
   11     0 [  8]                 ntdll!_SEH_epilog4 eax = 2ca880
   33   136 [  7]               ntdll!RtlpAllocateHeap eax = 2ca880
   44   169 [  6]             ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap eax = 2ca880
   14     0 [  5]           WINMM!WPP_INIT_CONTROL_ARRAY eax = 68d68f88
    7     0 [  8]                 WINMM!soundPlay eax = ffffffff`f7d0ed88
    7     0 [  8]                 WINMM!soundPlay eax = ffffffff`fbf886bb
   13     0 [  8]                 KERNELBASE!GetTickCount eax = 346883
    7     0 [  8]                 WINMM!soundPlay eax = ffffffff`ff48a886
    7     0 [  8]                 WINMM!soundPlay eax = 3010388
```

once you narrow down set specific breaks based on the sample data gathered

here is a specific scenerio you know the error code is 0xc0000034 and you know you dont want NtOpenKey which returns that value but some other api

you can employ some thing like this notic there is only one avast hook which return the error which you can latch on

```
>grep -i "eax =.*c.*34" foo.txt | grep -v -iE "ntopen|query|Image"
   18     0 [  8]                 KERNELBASE!BaseGetProcessDllPath eax = 2c634c
   51     0 [  8]                 KERNELBASE!BasepGetCachedPath eax = 2c634c
   18    80 [  7]               KERNELBASE!BaseGetProcessDllPath eax = 2c634c
   99     0 [  8]                 aswhookx eax = ffffffff`c0000034
```