# Windbg breakpoint on a register value

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, windbg

I want to put a breakpoint on a certain register that will fire whenever the register holds the value specified.

In the following example:

```
mov eax,10
mov ebx,12
inc eax
dec eax
```

Pseudocode:

```
bp @eax=0x10
```

I want to break at line 1 and line 4.

Note: I don't want to create a breakpoint on a certain address only.

Comment: I don't go here but it seems like you would have to trace the program and check for specific values every step of the trace. In my debugger that would look like `tp FFFFF while eax != 10 silent 1` but I don't know windbg.

Comment: You typically do have a location where you want to examine the register so you can set a [conditional breakpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-a-conditional-breakpoint). Otherwise, you must single step the whole program and test for the condition at every instruction but that will be very slow even if scripted.

Comment: @Jester: Well, of course x86 does have hardware data breakpoints (aka watchpoints) that trap whenever a particular address in memory is read/written.  Naturally it's not conditional on the value written; the debugger still has to test that in software whenever the data breakpoint traps.  But indeed there's no data breakpoints for registers.  So I agree that in this case you would have to manually set conditional breakpoints on every instruction that writes eax, or else single step.

Comment: If you have asm source, you may want to pepper the code with `cmp eax,10` `jne $+3` `bpHere: nop` and reassemble.

Comment: you may check here for some alternate flows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48785337/how-to-set-a-conditional-breakpoint-on-registers-value-in-windbg/48833576#48833576

Answer (score 2):

For breaking at certain memory addresses, WinDbg gets help from the CPU.

As [Microsoft states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/processor-breakpoints---ba-breakpoints-)

> For details of how this situation is handled on a specific processor, consult the processor archictecture [sic!] manual and look for "debug register" or "debug control register".

So, WinDbg uses the [debug registers DR0 to DR3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_debug_register) for data breakpoints on x86 machines.

I'm not overly familiar with the 4800 pages of the [Intel CPU Architecture document](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/intel-sdm.html) but I doubt that there is hardware support for register breakpoints.

So, if there's no hardware support, it does not mean it couldn't be done in software. However, that basically means your program would be single-stepped and the register value is checked after each instruction. This will become really slow.

While you can specify a command with the `p` command, note that it will step over `call` instructions, which is likely not what you want.

So you might want to think again if this is not a [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You think the solution is a register breakpoint. But what problem is there to be solved, for which you think register breakpoints is the solution? In my 14 years of debugging with WinDbg, I was never in need for breaking on a specific register value.